# Compiling a kernel with the Kolivas patch

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, patch

I am new to compiling kernels, and am struggling to apply the CK kernel patch.

As an example, I am trying to apply his 4.18 patch to a 4.18 kernel -- the files linked at the top of [this](http://ck.kolivas.org/) page.

I'm using Arch linux, and can successfully compile the kernel (without the patch) following the instructions given [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation#Bootloader_configuration). I can do this with the config file that ships with Arch (accepting the defaults to any queries when running `make nconfig`) or with `make localmodconfig` to get a slimmed down kernel.

Applying the patch (`patch -p1 < name_of_patch_file`), rebuilding the config with localmodconfig, and recompiling, consistently fails at the compilation stage.  With 4.19 kernels, I get `undefined reference to "sched_smt_present"`.  With 4.18 the errors get lost in the scrolling output, but the compile does not complete successfully.

I hope I have explained myself properly here -- apologies if not.  I am fully convinced that I am doing something wrong, and would very much appreciate any pointers you can give.

Comment: It could be that your are doing things right, but the patch conflict with the kernel and/or configuration you have. Report that to the developer of the patch. (Anywhere, we cannot help you without digging into the patch. And Stack Overflow is not a support site for 3d-part products.)

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. I'll look into making a report to the developer.